# Subsetting a list to remove character(0) elements

Tags: r

I want to remove list elements having `character(0)` from list of lists (unnamed). Below is the sample output. Please suggest how I should proceed.

```
[[984]]
character(0)

[[985]]
character(0)

[[986]]
[1] "Mazhar"       "LFG"          "Comments"     "coding"       "contribution" "quality"     

[[987]]
[1] "Comments" "good"    

[[988]]
[1] "Comments" "Quality"  "Good"     "team"    

[[989]]
 [1] "experience has vast" "Comments"            "effective"           "experience"         
 [5] "technologies"        "lead"                "team members"        "members"            
 [9] "team"                "good"               

[[990]]
[1] "bring the process" "processes"         "bring"             "guidelines"        "standards"        
[6] "handling"          "Comments"          "project"          

[[991]]
[1] "AEM"            "AEM though new"

[[992]]
[1] "communication"

[[993]]
character(0)

[[994]]
[1] "day"  "work"
```

Answer (score 4):

We could use `lengths` to create a logical vector.  The `length` for elements having `character(0)` would be 0.  So doing an equality comparison gets the logical vector for subsetting the `list`

```
out <- lst[lengths(lst)!=0]
```

---

Or another option is `Filter`

```
Filter(length, lst)
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(character(0), letters[1:3], character(0), letters[1:2])
```

Answer (score 3):

To eliminate list elements that are `character(0)`, we can negate `identical()`.

```
list[!sapply(list, identical, character(0))]
```

where `list` is your list.

Reproducible example:

```
x <- list(character(0), 1, 2, character(0))
x[!sapply(x, identical, character(0))]
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
```